# Erlang lhttpc:request error

Tags: erlang

i use

**https://github.com/esl/lhttpc**

this code run ok

```
-module(main).
-compile(export_all).

start()->  ssl:start(),  lhttpc:start(),
  Url="http://www.google.com",
  lhttpc:request(Url, get, [], 5000).
```

but this code

```
-module(main).
-compile(export_all).

start()->  ssl:start(),  lhttpc:start(),
  Url="http://www.google.com",

  case lhttpc:request(Url, get, [], 60000) of
    {ok, {{200, _}, _, Body}} ->
      io:format(Body),ok;
    Other ->
      exit({bad_result, Other})
  end.
```

generate error

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{bad_result,{error,{noproc,{gen_server,call,[undefined,{socket,<0.38.0>,"www.google.com",80,false},infinity]}}}}}
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a gen_server was not started or crashed. You can try starting erl with the

```
-boot start_sasl
```

option which might give you more insight as to what went wrong.  I think you might what something like this, not sure what you want to return in case of an error.

```
-module(main)
-compile(export_all).

    start()->  ssl:start(),  lhttpc:start(),
      Url="http://www.google.com",
      case lhttpc:request(Url, get, [], 60000) of
        {ok, {{200, _}, _, Body}} ->
          io:format("ok ~p~n",[Body]);
        { _,Other} ->
          io:format("error ~p~n",[Other])
      end.
```